# inverting strings (mirroring from center)

Tags: python, string

Isn't there a simpler way to invert a string like `EURUSD` to `USDEUR`, instead of using this code:

`new_str = old_str[-3:] + old_str[:3]`

Comment: not unless you have control of where the string comes from

Comment: What complexity do think there is in this code that can be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing shorter than what you are doing. I suspect that you were thinking of the trick for reversing a string, where `s[::-1]` reverses it. Here you are reversing by chunks of length 3. No one slice operation can do that.

If you do this sort of thing often, including for longer strings, writing a function might help:

```
def reverse_chunks(s,k):
    """reverses the order of k-sized chunks in s"""
    return ''.join([s[i:i+k] for i in range(0,len(s),k)][::-1])
```

Then, for example:

```
>>> reverse_chunks('EURUSD',3)
'USDEUR'
```

Based on this, you could of course write a more specialized:

```
def invert(s):
    return reverse_chunks(s,len(s)//2)
```